# How to fill a MenuItem dynamically during runtime with MenuItems?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, menuitem

I have the following (simplified) view model:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    ObservableCollection<RackViewModel> Racks { get; set; }
}

public class RackViewModel
{
    public string Header { get; set; }

    public ICommand ActivateCommand { get; }

    public ICommand ShowInfoCommand { get; }
}
```

The viewmodel classes of course implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, which I omitted for brevity. I want to display the racks in menu bar of the window. I tried it like this:

```
<Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
<MenuItem Header="Racks">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Racks}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemContainerTemplate>
                            <MenuItem Header="{Binding Header}">
                                <MenuItem Command="{Binding ActivateCommand}" Header="Activate"/>
                                <MenuItem Command="{Binding ShowInfoCommand}" Header="Show Information"/>
                            </MenuItem>
                        </ItemContainerTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

This gives me the following result:

[image]

When I hover with the mouse over the menu, all items are marked at the same time and I can't access the submenus. I expected it to be the following:

[image]

Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Comment: Your issue is that the `RackViewModel` class isn't hierarchical.

Comment: @mm8: Thanks for your comment. Can you tell me a bit more about how to make `RackViewModel` hierarchical?

Comment: Add an `IEnumerable<RackViewModel>` property to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ItemSource` Property

Look something like:

```
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="Click me" Command="{Binding ChangeCommand}"></MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Items" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Children}"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
```

and your `ViewModel` could look like:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
        ChangeCommand = new RelayCommand(ChangeCollection);
        SomethingCommand = new RelayCommand(DoSomething);
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello World");
    }

    private void ChangeCollection()
    {
        this.Items.Clear();

        Items.Add(new MenuItem{Header = "Test 1"});
        Items.Add(new MenuItem{Header = "Test 2", Command = SomethingCommand});
        Items.Add(new MenuItem{Header = "Test 3"});
    }

    public RelayCommand SomethingCommand {get; set;}
    public RelayCommand ChangeCommand { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

MenuItem class:

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public MenuItem()
    {
        Children = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
    }
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> Children { get; set; }
    public ICommand Command { get; set; }
}
```

To add the children just select the `MenuItem` that you want to change the children and add or remove to that MenuItem.Children property.

Comment: In my question I stated that I want to put `MenuItem`s into the `MenuItem`s. See the second picture I posted. How can I do this with this approach? I already tried a `<Setter Property="ItemsSource">`, but all the styles where also applied to the nested `MenuItem`s (and hence I got an infinite recursion). Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Okay, I'll make adjustments.